# volatile overloading?

Tags: c++, overloading, volatile

I heard that volatile is factor of overloading like const.

If a function is overloaded by volatile parameter,
when is the volatile-version called?

I can't imagine a situation when the volatile-version is called.

Comment: Added C++ tag; if that's not the language you're talking about, please edit your question to mention that rather important fact and retag appropriately.

Comment: This is just similar to `const`, If you have a `volatile` qualified object then only `volatile` function can be called on it.

Comment: In general, almost anything that applies to `const` qualifiers also applies to `volatile` qualifiers. The standard mostly refers to them collectively as _cv-qualifiers_.

Comment: [Here](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/184403766) is an interesting use (or perhaps abuse) of `volatile` member functions to give a compile-time check that an object is being accessed in a thread-safe way. Basically, you access unlocked objects via `volatile` references and locked objects via normal references, and each operation has a `volatile` overload that acquires the lock first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Volatile can be applied to parameters, but it is not a factor of overloading when applied directly to the parameter.  It is however possible to use it to distinguish types of the parameter.  For example, this is legal:

```
void f(int &p) {}; //reference to int
void f(volatile int &p) {}; //reference to volatile int
```

This is not:

```
void f(int p) {};
void f(volatile int p) {};
```

The reason is that in the first example the reference is not what is volatile, but the integer.  In the second example, both types are integers and therefore the same type.

There are also volatile methods.  They are akin to declaring `this` to be volatile.  Because `this` is a pointer and not the containing type itself, the following is also legal:

```
void c::f(int p) {};
void c::f(int p) volatile {};
```

It is all the same as for overloading by `const`.

This relevant part of the C++ standard is §13.1 *Overloadable declarations*. From C++11 draft n3290:

> Parameter declarations that differ only in the presence or absence of const and/or volatile are equivalent. That is, the const and volatile type-specifiers for each parameter type are ignored when determining which function is being declared, defined, or called. [ Example:

```
typedef const int cInt;
int f(int);
int f(const int);          // redeclaration of f(int)
int f(int) { /* ... */ }   // definition of f(int)
int f(cInt) { /* ... */ }  // error: redefinition of f(int)
```

> — end example ]
>
> Only the const and volatile type-specifiers at the outermost level of the parameter type specification are ignored in this fashion; const and volatile type-specifiers buried within a parameter type specification are significant and can be used to distinguish overloaded function declarations<sup>124</sup>. In particular, for any type T, `pointer to T`, `pointer to const T`, and `pointer to volatile T` are considered distinct parameter types, as are `reference to T`, `reference to const T`, and `reference to volatile T`.
>
> <sub>124) When a parameter type includes a function type, such as in the case of a parameter type that is a pointer to function, the
>   const and volatile type-specifiers at the outermost level of the parameter type specifications for the inner function type are
>   also ignored.</sub>

Answer (score 10):

Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "in non-volatile" << std::endl;
    }
    void foo() volatile {
        std::cout << "in volatile" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.foo();
    volatile A b;
    b.foo();
}
```

`b.foo()` will call the `volatile` overload. If `struct A` didn't have a volatile overload for `foo`, `b.foo()` would be invalid.

Comment: Not so quick. This question seems to be about volatile parameters, and those are not a factor of overloading.

Comment: That wasn't (isn't) entirely clear to me - and Pete already posted an answer about function parameters.

Comment: I'm fine with that, but @Pete also isn't giving the full answer.  Maybe we should consolidate.

Comment: To do that, I incorporated your good point into the accepted answer and upvoted you.

Comment: I incorporated a quote from the standard to yours, hope you don't mind :)

Answer (score 3):

Write a test program to find out.

```
void func(const int& a)
{
    std::cout << "func(const)" << std::endl;
}

void func(const volatile int& a)
{
    std::cout << "func(const volatile)" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    const int a = 0;
    const volatile int b = 0;
    func(a);
    func(b);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

will output:

```
func(const)
func(const volatile)
```